# Disable cloud synchronization of settings in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So, I've been experiencing an annoying issue in VS2013. Basically, whenever I restart Visual Studio it'll give me that lovely "loading user settings" box and then it will load my cloud synchronized settings. However, it never appears to actually save these settings. It always sets things like C# brace completion to on, despite me turning it off every time I start Visual Studio.

I've gave up on trying to figure out what's wrong with it and had rather to just disable the synchronization. How can I do this?

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Synchronized Settings` to turn synchronization on or off for different settings categories on that computer.[image]

Comment: In visual studio 2017 this is now under Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts