# Visual Studio different settings for 2015 and 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, user-profile

I have VS2015 and VS2017 installed on my machine but I need to have different settings for them. However every time I change something in VS2015 the same configuration is applied in VS2017 and vice-versa.(Ex: on VS2017 I need to have the tab with 3 spaces and on VS2015 with 4 spaces)

Is there a way to break this?

Comment: @Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089086/disable-cloud-synchronization-of-settings-in-visual-studio-2013]

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make a lot of sense.  I suspect you are doing this on the same solution, opening it both in VS2015 and VS2017.  Window layout is saved in the hidden .suo file for the solution.  But with VS2017 anything is possible, use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to tools-->Options-->Environment-->Accounts to turn synchronization on or off for different settings categories on that computer.